# How to get image preview in symfony collection images

Tags: jquery, html, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, php-5.4

I am working with SonataAdminBundle in a symfony2 project in which my admin class is as given below :

```
class ApartmentsAdmin extends Admin
 {
     protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
      {
         ->add('images', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new ImageType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => true,
                'mapped' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Apartment Images'
              ));
           }
       }
```

It works fine ; but my issue is that , on edit page i want to let see preview of each images included in collection of images. In documentation of "SonataAdminBundle" image preview is given for one individual image , but how is it possible to make preview for collection images ..

Please suggest me..

Thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to do this through "custom Form Type Extension" for which documentation is given on the link "http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html" .